# How to disable "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing" for a dialog

Tags: c++, winapi

There is an popping up dialog with `WS_POPUP` style. When OK button pressed, application instantly makes screen capture. "Fading" animation causes half-closed dialog appear on the image.

I tried to use `DS_CONTROL` style, but in this case dialog looks weird and ugly.
I also tried to disabling visual effect "**Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing**", but it applies for the whole system, and not acceptable for app.

How could we disable animation effect for one dialog?

Comment: Maybe hide the dialog with `ShowWindow` when OK is pressed, before destroying it? `ShowWindow` is supposed to hide instantly, with no animation.

Comment: Try `DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED`.

Comment: Or, you could move the dialog off-screen before taking the screen capture, and then move the dialog back when done.

Comment: Thank you @Raymond Chen. It indeed works.